# How to import, manipulate and combine multiple files in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have multiple `pdf` files from a website to import and manipulate. My main goal is to make **each row of the dataframe** I'm building to be the **content of each pdf**. Let's say the `pdf` files follow this pattern:

```
https://www.website.com/files/file1.pdf
https://www.website.com/files/file2.pdf
https://www.website.com/files/file3.pdf
```

The first step is to import all those files. I can import each one of them, separately, like this:

```
link <- "https://www.website.com/files/file1.pdf"
df <- data.frame(pdftools::pdf_text(link))
```

The first issue is that I need to import multiple files, not only one.

After that, I have to make some manipulations on that `df`. Let's say:

```
df_clean <- df %>% 
  rename(text = 1) %>% 
  mutate(Date = str_sub(text[1], start = 10, end = 18),
         text = str_squish(text)) %>% 
  tail(-2) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste(text, collapse = " "))
```

This process results in a dataframe with 1 observation and 2 variables:

```
     Date              text
     01/01/2022        This is the text of file 1
```

The problem is that I need to make this process to every file that I import, with the goal of **each observation being the text in each file imported**, like this:

```
     Date              text
     01/01/2022        This is the text of file 1
     01/02/2022        This is the text of file 2
     01/03/2022        This is the text of file 3
```

Any ideas on how to proceed? Do I need to make a for loop to import and manipulate every file? Thanks!

Comment: `data.frame(url=c("https://...","...","...")) %>% mutate(text = lapply(url, function(U) pdftools::pdf_text(U)))` might work

Comment: Here's a tutorial walking through a similar process but with a different function (read_csv instead of pdf_text): https://www.gerkelab.com/blog/2018/09/import-directory-csv-purrr-readr/